# How to create and download CSV from Django Template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm fairly new to Django and haven't done much with serving files and have only ever pulled and pushed from forms using Django Templates.

My goal is this:

Using the information collected in a form from the user, query my DB and create a CSV that will download to the user.

Is this possible with a template based page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use default django's `csv.writer`

```
# In this example csv_request is the request model to save how many CSV requests came via your form
# DataForCSVModel is the Model you want to download as CSV

import csv
from django.http import HttpResponse

def some_view(request):
    # your business logic or whatever goes here
    if form.is_valid():
        csv_request = form.save(commit=False)
        csv_request.requested_by = request.user
        csv_request.requested_date= timezone.now()
        csv_request.save()

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="csv_filename.csv"'

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    [writer.writerow() for a in DataForCSVModel.objects.filter(<use csv_request object's data to filter>).values_list('id', 'name', 'place')]
    # Or if you want to write something else write like this
    # writer.writerow(['hello', 'world', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'])

    return response
```

Or

If you dont want to take the risk use django-queryset-csv

Install https://github.com/azavea/django-queryset-csv

```
from djqscsv import render_to_csv_response

def csv_view(request):
  qs = Foo.objects.filter(bar=True).values('id', 'bar')
  return render_to_csv_response(qs)
```

Comment: i was searching since months how to export to CSV something different than the pure __str__ and the .values_list literally gave me the way. Thanks mate!!

Answer (score -1):

For generating csv I prefer pandas,Firstly make a dataframe and then convert the dataframe easily to CSV

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(python_list_name)
df.to_csv('fullpath_file.csv')
```